# MySQL reuse missed primary key int values when maxed out

Tags: mysql, indexing, alter-table

One of our tables unexpectedly ran out of Ids. A quick look at the table I can see not all Ids have been used. I assume this where we may have deleted data for reasons.

I've been reading that the nature of mysql's auto_inc field means it always goes +1 for the next Id.

Is there a way to tell it to use unused Ids?

I've been reading here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html
But I'm not a super DB dev, and I don't really get if this will do what I'm hoping for.

Our first plan is to change the Id to be Unsigned() and gain an extra couple billion rows. But this is a quick fix to a problem that we shouldnt be near *yet*.
The table is in constant use, in production, but our system does have a "retry" concept. So if this table is out of action for a bit, that is fine for us.

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: 'Is there a way to tell it to use unused Ids?' - only if you hand roll. What datatype is the id column,

Comment: I was worried that be the response tbh. The datatype is Int(11)

Comment: (11) means display 11 characters not that the column stores as 11 digits. Please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html for max integer size and consider changing to bigint.

Comment: Well it's INT (32bit). Switch to BIGINT (64bit). Or fix your software, which is "burning" to many IDs.

Comment: Yeah we're looking at migrating to BigInt as the long term solution.
The "burning too many Ids" is a fair point, but as I was asking - just curious if you can reuse unused Ids.

Comment: Reuse - not really. An auto_increment ID is always increasing. Many of us need that to be guaranteed (e.g. to find the latest entry).

Comment: Yeah of course, our system doesnt care about it auto_inc, I guess, just that is gauranteed to be unique. 
Looks like migrating to unsigned() and then BigInt is our short and long term solutions?

Comment: When INT is too small - That's what **BIG**INT is for :-)  Seriously - We know about nothing about your database, the table and the column. (G)UID could also be an option. But in 99% of cases like this, BIGINT is the solution.

Comment: Thank you, it's seeming that way! I'm going to start preparing for this large alter... Is it worth using unsigned aswell ?

Comment: If the data is unsiggned, then I always use UNSIGNED as data type - Unless I'm too lazy to type that one more word :-)

Comment: lol cheers paul. For us it would never be a negative Int, just always a positive unique Id. So I'll migrate to both bigint and unsigned, thanks :)

Comment: @P.Salmon - Actually the `(11)` means nothing unless used with `ZEROFILL`.  And it has been _removed_ from 8.0.

Comment: Subtraction is something that can bite `UNSIGNED` values.  But presumably you never do arithmetic with the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

No, there is no way to tell MySQL's auto-increment to generate values that "fill in the gaps" in the table.

Even if you try to alter the table to reset the next increment value, it will immediately adjust itself up to the current MAX(id)+1. It will not generate an auto-increment value less than the max auto-increment currently in the table.

You can do an INSERT to override the auto-increment and specify a value yourself. But it's up to you to find the values that are unused.

That introduces race conditions. Even if you check for an unused value, some other client could grab it the instant after you read that, before you use it in an INSERT.

To avoid the race condition, you'd have to lock the whole table, to prevent another client from inserting. Then your session could do a query to find a missing value, then insert, then unlock the table.

There are several good reasons for the limitation of auto-increment not filling in gaps.

- It simplifies the internal implementation. It only needs to keep track of one value per table. Simpler implementation usually means less chance for bugs.
- There is no table-lock needed to search for the next value. Allocating the next value is implemented by a brief mutex lock. This allows many concurrent clients to insert freely, without waiting.
- There might have been a good reason for the gap.

This scenario is a bit complicated, but it illustrates that such scenarios could exist:

Suppose the id 12345 in a `users` table corresponds to a user who was banned for sending harassing emails to other users. Their account was prohibited and banned, and the row in the `users` table for their account was deleted. Later, if you find that gap and assume it was never used, so you allocate that id 12345 to the next new user. They now unfortunately are associated with the id of that banned user.

Then one of the original abusive emails is discovered by someone who checks their email infrequently. The recipient complains about user 12345. *But that id now belongs to the new innocent user,* and they don't deserve to be accused as sending harassing emails.

Comment: I agree with your post, in general, but in a perfect world the scenario you describe as a reason not to fill the gaps should be taken care of by foriegn keys and thus if the source row is deleted then the corresponding values in other places are `NULL`ed or removed themselves. so spam user `12345` would cease to exist. This would still cause an issue with the delayed email from that user id but..... Foreign keys fix most of the obvious issues

Comment: It's just a hypothetical example of a case where reusing supposedly "missed" id values might cause unforeseen problems. Besides, it's unnecessary. Just use BIGINT if you have a large table, and you'll never have to worry about running out of values.

Answer (score 1):

If your AUTO_INCREMENT value gets close to the max INT value due to many deletions, then switching to BIGINT should be the simpliest solution. You can estimate, how long it would take until you will also burn down all BIGINT values. If the estimated number in years is one that you know no name for, then you should be safe for a while.

There are also other options like UUID. But if INT worked well until now, then BIGINT should aswell.